# Persistent User Session on React Native App

Tags: react-native, authentication

I have already implemented a user authentication, in which the user can log in again or register.

I would now like to avoid that the user must register again after each closing of the app.  For this reason I have to request a refresh token at certain intervals (Max 1 hour, as long as the cookie is valid).  my question: how do I do that best?  the refresh should work for both open and closed apps.  I saw the possibility of the React Native Background task, but apparently only runs when the app is closed.

Comment: Are you using Firebase for authentication

Comment: No, I am using a „self-made“ authentification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a flag in [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) when the user is authenticated.

And then you have to check that flag each time on opening the app.

Here is the sample snippet.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);
```

And in your app.js you can check this flag in constructor

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('loggedIn').then((value) => {
        if (value) {
           //user logged in logic goes here
        } else {
         // user logged out. You need to login him again
        }
     });
```

Comment: But how can I check the expiration time and refresh it if it is necessery? What I am looking for is a handling like whatsapp has. I want to refresh token before the expiration time is running out, so that the user does not has to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you need to **persist user's login forever and still be able to refresh the token**, one possible way is to store the user's credentials (username and password) in some secure storage like [react-native-keychain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keychain) and then refresh the token every time the user opens the app.

Or more precisely, automate the login with the credentials you stored whenever the user launches the app with the help of [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook(componentDidMount).

*Note: This is not a good implementation if your app uses push notifications. Push notifications demand the user to be authorized all the time.*