# How to keep a user logged in (even when phone turns off ) on a React Native app with Django backend?

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, authentication

I am beginning to code with react native and I am trying my first app. I am in the process of making the login/signup of the app. I managed to log the user in but I cannot seem to figure out how to keep the user logged in when I close the app. How can I keep a user logged in to the app even when the app is closed?

This is what I have-

login.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, Button, Pressable, ScrollView  } from 'react-native';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';






export default function Login(props) {

  const message = props.navigation.getParam('message', null)
  const [ username, setUsername ] = useState("")
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState("")

  

  const log = () => {

    fetch(`http://192.168.5.223:8000/home/login/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": 'application/json'
         },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}),
  })
  .then( res => res.json())
  .then( res => {
    console.log(res)
    
    if (res.valid === true){
      
      if (res.set === true){
        props.navigation.navigate("Home", {"user": username})
      } else {
        props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {"user": username})
      }
      
    } else {
      props.navigation.navigate("Login", {'message': "username/password are incorrect"})
    }
    

  })
  .catch( error => console.log(error))
  


  



  }

  const sign = () => {

    props.navigation.navigate("Signup")

  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scroll} >
      <View style={styles.main}>
      <Text style={styles.error}>{message}</Text>  
      <Text style={styles.label}>
        Username: 
      </Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username" 
        onChangeText={ text => setUsername(text)} value={username}
        autoCapitalize={'none'}
         />
      
      <Text style={styles.label}>Password:</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password" onChangeText={ text => setPassword(text)}
        value={password} secureTextEntry={true} autoCapitalize={'none'}
      />

      
      <Button onPress={ () => log()} title="Login"></Button>
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <Button onPress={ () => sign()} title="Don't have an acount? Sign up now" />
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto"/>
    </View>


  )


}

Login.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
  headerLeft: () => null,
  gestureEnabled: false,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
  headerTintColor: 'white',

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your a user session to be persisted when the user closes and reopens the app you can use the AsyncStorage API.

See for instance this question [Persistent User Session on React Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866077/persistent-user-session-on-react-native-app)

You need to store a token/cookie that will be used by your server to authenticate the user.